# Cofactor Expansion 4x4 linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Compute the determinant by cofactor expansions.

A=

```
   | 1 -2  5  2|
   | 0  0  3  0|
   | 2 -4 -3  5|
   | 2  0  3  5|
```

I figured the easiest way to compute this problem would be to use a cofactor across row 2. So I got:

det A =

```
    |-1 -2  2|
  -3| 2 -4  5|
    | 2  0  5|
```

I went on to factor across the third row.

det A =

```
         ( |-2  2|    |-1 -2|)
       -3(2|-4  5| + 5| 2 -4|)
```

det A = -3(2(-10+8)+5(4+4))

det A = -3(-4+40)

det A = -108

When I check my work on a determinate calculator I see that I should be getting det A = 12, but I can't seem to see where I'm messing up.

Comment: You changed the sign of the upper left element: in your matrix it is $\;1\;$ , but then you changed it to $\;-1\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

The top left entry on the second matrix got copied wrong, it should be 1 not -1.